# Simple C: atof giving wrong value

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program that reads input from a singe line(string obviously) and organizes it into arrays.

The problem I have is that at one point the program reads two different values and returns the first one twice. Initially I thought the program was reading the same value twice but when I tested it turned out that it got the correct one but is inputting the wrong one.

for example

> Input: 2  0.90 0.75 0.7 0.65

sorry to snip it

```
(while(fgets (string[test], sizeof(string[test]),ifp))
pch = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &prog);
tem3 = atoi(pch);
while (loop<tem3)
{
    pch=strtok_r(NULL," ",&prog);
    venseatfloat[test][loop][DISCOUNT][OCCUPIED]=(float)atof(pch);
    printf("%f is discount\t",venseatfloat[test][loop][DISCOUNT][OCCUPIED]);

    pch=strtok_r(NULL, " ", &prog);
    strcpy(temp, pch);
    venseatfloat[test][loop][REGULAR][OCCUPIED]=(float)atof(pch);
    printf("%s is the string but %.3f is regular\n", temp ,venseatfloat[test][loop][DISCOUNT][OCCUPIED]);
    loop++;

}
```

output:

```
>0.900000 is discount    0.75 is the string but 0.900 is regular

>0.700000 is discount    0.65 is the string but 0.700 is regular
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

In the second read, you're reading venseatfloat[test][loop][REGULAR][OCCUPIED], but printf'ing venseatfloat[test][loop][DISCOUNT][OCCUPIED]. (Note REGULAR vs. DISCOUNT.)

Comment: Ughhhh wow. I am a moron. Sorry to steal from your time.

I have to go pound my head on a wall now.

Comment: @Doc, If that's really the solution, then you need to accept the answer.

Comment: heh... we're all morons three days out of five :)